# iOS5 adding and manipulting a UIView class

Tags: uiview, ios5, xcode4.2

I have create a UIVeiw class and a .xib.  Within this .xib view I have its set to freeform with the dimensions of 400x200 and I have assigned it to my custom class with the same name:

Storyboard: blogView
Class Files: blogView.h & blogView.m

Within in the .xib i have added a label and a text field and linked them up to variable within the .h files etc (See code below).

blogCont.h

```
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

  @interface blogCont : UIView
  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lbBlogDate;
  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *txtBlogTitle;

  @end
```

blogCont.m

```
  #import "newsStoryView.h"

  @implementation blogCont
  @synthesize lbBlogDate;
  @synthesize txtBlogTitle;

  - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
  {
      self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
      if (self) {
          // Initialization code place a log to see if it loads
          NSLog(@"View Loaded");


      }
      return self;
  }
  @end
```

Now with in my main viewController.m file i have added the following code to init this view class, and I have added a background colour to see if this loads in.

viewController.m

```
 UIView *blogCont = [[blogView alloc] init];
 blogCont.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
 [subview addSubview:blogCont];
```

Now when I run this it all works well but as I do not see the purple background it looks as if the view does not load, but within the log I do see the NSLog message I have within this view NSLog(@"View Loaded"); so it seems it initiating this, but I cannot for the life of me get this to display?

Now if I change the code slightly to my main View Controller.m fiel to:

```
 CGRect blogFrame;
 blogFrame.origin.x = 20;
 blogFrame.origin.y = 20;
 blogFrame.size = CGRectMake(400,200);;


 newsStoryView *blogCont = [[blogView alloc] blogFrame];
 blogCont.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
 [subview addSubview:blogCont];
```

Then I get my view display a nice purple box, so this shows up when I set a frame size and the init the view with it 'blogFrame', bu tI thought that all this would be set within the .xib settings so no need to do this?

SO how can I create this external view class and assign it into another view and then manipulate its data, as accessing the label in the .xib using blogCont.lbBlogDate.text does not seem to work that is it probably does but as I cannot view it i cannot confirm it.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems I nearly answered my own question then did:

I was not setting the size within my separate class view I was asking for a size when init it:

```
  - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
```

this is asking for a size

so I could do the following to the above:

```
  - (id)init
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 478, 220)];
  .... rest of code
```

Setting the size within the view load.

But I could also set it when I init it in my main view controller as below:

```
 newsStoryView *blogCont = [[blogView alloc]  initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 200)];
```

This is better as I can control the position of each one. Hope this helps anyone